# 1990s D&D Style book - Hero is a female who seeks training

Tags: story-identification

I read this book in the 90s and it may be part of a series. I remember a girl who approaches a knight (for training?). He is unhappy about it, tries to get rid of her but, if I remember correctly, trains her after having hit her.

Does anyone remember this book/series?

Comment: Do you remember anything else? Character names? Descriptions of the characters? What training does she receive? Is there magic? Who is the enemy? What is the plot? Was the training the whole of the novel or did she leave the knight and have adventures without him? Was this a kids/young-adult novel or an adult novel?

Comment: Sorry for the late reply. Unfortunately, I could not remember more.

Comment: No worries. Glad you found it. Admittedly I'm also astounded anyone recognised it.

Comment: Me too, I tried finding it for quite some time before I found this site, really awesome!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Could this be [The Tainted Sword](http://www.goodreads.com/book/show/1060733.The_Tainted_Sword) by D.J. Heinrich (1st book of the [Penhaligon Trilogy](http://www.goodreads.com/series/43837-the-penhaligon-trilogy))?

> An aging knight--once the embodiment of glory and honor, but who has fallen into disrepute--reluctantly takes on a waif who has proclaimed herself his squire and a young man who dreams of becoming a mage. To restore the knight's good name, they must confront the green dragon who has dedicated its life to destroying the knight's fame.

[image]

The above is a D&D novel from TSR.

There is also a similar (situational) non-D&D book called [The Paladin](http://www.goodreads.com/book/show/57096.The_Paladin?from_search=true&search_version=service) by C.J. Cherryh.

Comment: Thank you very much. This is the book I was looking for.